# error when using tkinter wraplength function

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I want the output inside the label auto line break. I see many people use the function wrap length but when I use it like this

```
label_out.place(relx=0, rely=0.05, relwidth=1, relheight=0.95, wraplengt=200)
```

it shows

```
TclError: unknown option "-wraplength"
```

I know where I have done wrong now, I correct my code to this

```
    final_text = ' '.join([lemmatizer.lemmatize(w) for w in stemmed])
    label_out = Label(root,font="helvetica 14", wraplength=300,justify="center")
    label_out['text'] = final_text
```

and now I got another error

```
AttributeError: 'xml.etree.ElementTree.Element' object has no attribute 'tk'
```

Comment: `wraplength` is the option of widget. You can use it with config method. Why are you using with geometry manager.

Comment: `wraplength` is a [`Label` widget **option**](https://web.archive.org/web/20190429181150id_/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/label.html), not a valid argument to pass to `place()` — which is why you're getting the exception.

Answer (score 1):

As the error says `Label.place` doesn't support `wraplength` option. `wraplength` is for widgets. you can change your code to something like this

```
label_out= Label(root, text="Your long text", font="helvetica 14",wraplength=300, justify="center")
```

Answer (score 0):

I just find the solution. At first, I think the wraplength should put in the final but I was wrong( not totally) it should not put like this.

```
label_out = tk.Label(lower_frame, bg='white')
label_out.place(relx=0, rely=0.05, relwidth=1, relheight=0.95, wraplength=500)
```

instead, it should put like this

```
label_out = tk.Label(lower_frame, bg='white', wraplength=500)
label_out.place(relx=0, rely=0.05, relwidth=1, relheight=0.95)
```

most of the answer put all thing in one sentence. In fact, it can write like this

```
label_out['text'] = final_text

label_out = tk.Label(lower_frame, bg='white', wraplength=500)
label_out.place(relx=0, rely=0.05, relwidth=1, relheight=0.95)
```

using this method you(I) can put all the stuff about UI at the end of the code, leaving only variable in the upper part of the code.